# Uncaught ReferenceError Taxi is not defines

Tags: javascript, object

```js
var taxi = {
    Make: "Thundi Motors",
    Model: "Nissan",
    Year : 1986,
    Color : "Yellow-Black",
    Passengers : 5,
    Transmisson : "Automatic",
    Mileage : 97000
};

var Mazda = {
    Make : " 808",
    Model : "Classic",
    Year : 1979,
    Color : "Brown",
    Passengers : 5,
    Transmisson : "Manual",
    Mileage : 312000
};

  function eligible(car) {
      if(car.Mileage > 10000) {
          return false;
      }
      else if (car.Year > 1985){
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
var worthLook = eligible(Taxi);

if (worthLook) {
    console.log("Go for this" );
} else {
    console.log ("Think again for this");
}
```

[Car Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POI4f.jpg)I have been trying this code and many time i got message Uncaught ReferenceError: Taxi is not defined
    at index.js:190 , although sometime the created object execute fine in console when i try taxi.model or taxi.year etc?

Further the conditional code is behaving abnormal and executing second console line all the time.

I would appreciate upon resolution of this.

The code images are attached.

Comment: Hi, could you paste your code in a snippet rather than having images of screenshot of your codes ? Thanks.

Comment: There are also no images attached whatsoever.

Comment: I have enabled the image option

Comment: Please click on Car Code for image view.

Comment: I have pasted the code in snippet

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variables are case sensitive, this mean `Foo` and `foo`, or in your case `Taxi` and `taxi`, are not the same variable. You need to replace your `Taxi` variable to be `taxi` in your `eligible` function call.

```js
var taxi = {
    Make: "Thundi Motors",
    Model: "Nissan",
    Year : 1986,
    Color : "Yellow-Black",
    Passengers : 5,
    Transmisson : "Automatic",
    Mileage : 97000
};

var Mazda = {
    Make : " 808",
    Model : "Classic",
    Year : 1979,
    Color : "Brown",
    Passengers : 5,
    Transmisson : "Manual",
    Mileage : 312000
};

  function eligible(car) {
      if(car.Mileage > 10000) {
          return false;
      }
      else if (car.Year > 1985){
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
var worthLook = eligible(taxi);
//-----------------------^^^^^
if (worthLook) {
    console.log("Go for this" );
} else {
    console.log ("Think again for this");
}
```